# Reroute with extra parameter for multi language sites in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

In my codeigniter webapp, I'm using multi language site. Default and in english like these:

```
www.xxx.com (default)
www.xxx.com/en (english)
```

And I have a controller where I want to re-route specific calls say potato and tomato to vegie like these:

```
www.xxx.com/potato/param => www.xxx.com/vegie/param
www.xxx.com/tomato/param => www.xxx.com/vegie/param
```

So far, I have managed to reroute with default language url using like this in my route.php:

```
$route['potato/(.+)$'] = 'vegie/$1';
$route['tomato/(.+)$'] = 'vegie/$1';
```

But I doesn't work for the english site. I did like this, and not working:

```
$route['en/potato/(.+)$'] = 'en/vegie/$1';
$route['en/tomato/(.+)$'] = 'en/vegie/$1';
```

Anyone can help me for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, create new function to manage the english version, ex: function vegie_en()

then route to it

```
$route['en/potato/(:any)'] = 'vegie_en/$1';
```

Comment: shar_evonz, i think u didn't quite undesrtand my situation. the one not working is not the deault url, but for the english with en/

Comment: based on your route: $route['en/potato/(.+)$'] = 'en/vegie/$1';
u should have function named 'en' in your default controller

Comment: or simply, create new function to handle that english version, then route to it. Ex: $route['en/potato/(:any)'] = 'vegie_en/$1';

Comment: if i create another function, means i duplicate the code which I don't want. I want to use just one single code because the process are just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I have this in my route.php which makes it rerouting wrongly if there's prefix en/:

```
$route['en/(.+)$'] = '$1';
```

I moved this to the end of the route.php and it working very fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem in my project. I fixed it by removing the 'en' and put $2 as for dynamic value.
So in your case, this will work.Please try this given below code.
`$route['en/potato/(.+)$'] = 'vegie/$2';
$route['en/tomato/(.+)$'] = 'vegie/$2';`